# How to use Firebase in Chrome extension content script

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a Chrome extension and I would like to load Firebase Firestore into my content script. I have looked at stack overflow: [Firebase not getting loaded in chrome extension content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569565/firebase-not-getting-loaded-in-chrome-extension-content-script) but for the love of my life I can not get this to work. I understand that it is asking me to download the Firebase JDK and include it in my extension but I can not get it to load properly. I always get the error **firebase is not defined**.

Here is my manifast:

```
  "content_scripts":[
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },  
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/tiny.png",
      "32": "images/log32.png",
      "48": "images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/tiny.png",
    "32": "images/log32.png",
    "48": "images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "images/get_started128.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self'  https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com https://apis.google.com/; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Content scripts can't make cross-origin network requests in modern Chrome so I don't think it would make sense to use Firebase there.